# Unable to add elements to an array dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays, html

I am trying to create a dynamic array and push elements to it using Javascript. Being a beginner, I am having problems with it.

P.S. I am fetching the values all fine (checked with console.log), the only problem is that I am unable to put it in the database.

Below is my code -

```
 (function makelist() {
    var listHeaderData =[];
    var listChildData = [];
    var listImagePath = [];
    var nextPageRefLink = ['imageSlider.html','NewsItem_descp_1.html','http://www.yahoo.com'];
    Parse.initialize("XN0sv3fBqB380fCpwohuHAgansghkiDp8MhbyJDs", "xzoETxUUxicHAtdwqbZh65XtTAFaona3a6cC9jSB");
    console.log("Parse Initailized inside javascript");
    var newsFeed = Parse.Object.extend("NewsFeed");
    var query = new Parse.Query(newsFeed);
    query.find ({
        success: function(results) {
            var output ="";
            for(var  i in results) {
                //listHeaderData DATA
                var heading = results[i].get("Heading");
                listHeaderData.push(heading);
                console.log("Header : "+heading);
                //listChildData DATA
                var description = results[i].get("description");
                listChildData.push(description);
                console.log("Description : "+description);
                if(results[i].get("Image")) {
                    var file = results[i].get("Image");
                    //listImagePath URL's
                    var url = file.url();
                    listImagePath.push(url);
                    console.log("Image URL is:"+url);
                }
                console.log("Heading:"+heading);
                console.log("Description:"+description);
            }
        } , error: function(error){
            console.log("Query error :"+error.message);
        }
    }); 
}
```

The problem is nothing is getting added to the arrays that I have defined above. I am using .push() function for it. What can be the problem ?

Comment: You would be better off using `for(var i=0; i < results.length; i += 1)`  for a start as you don't want to be checking all the properties on the `results` object, just the array values.

Comment: When and/or When you had the problem? What precisely problem?

Comment: @frikinside I have corrected my post. The problem is nothing is getting added to the arrays that I have defined above. I am using .push() function for it.

Comment: is the console.log(url) logging the right data?

Comment: @JosephKhella Yes it is...

Comment: try setting  
var url = "foo";  
url = file.url();  
and check what's the pushed value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you use these `list*` variables?

If you try to access `listHeaderData` right after `query.find()` then you will never get the data as it will be available later, after `query.find` request is finished. This is why you need to check these arrays right after the for-loop within `success` callback.

Comment: No that isn't the problem. I have correct my post. The problem is that nothing is getting added to the array via the .push()  function.

Comment: Your `list*` variables exist within `makelist()` function scope, populated asynchronously after the response arrives in `query.find()` call. Could you tell me where you use these `list*` variables?

Comment: Right...Below this code I have more code written that dynamically creates html elements through the same script. Like this :   var spanTag = document.createElement("span");
    spanTag.setAttribute("class", "title");
    spanTag.innerHTML = listHeaderData[i];

Comment: This is the problem. Put this code after the for-loop. for (var i in results) { /*...*/ }; var spanTag...